# Principal Ideal Ring which is not Integral

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

In *Atiyah & McDonald: Commutative Algebra* the Principal Ideal Domain is a principal ideal **ring** which is **also** an integral domain.

I tried but couldn't find examples of commutative rings with identity that have the property that every ideal is generated by a single element but are not integral. Any suggestions ?

I believe that the fact that the set of all zero-divisors is not closed under "$+$" (in $\mathbb{Z_6}$ for example $3+2=5$) is making the search of such example difficult.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_4$ not integral domain and  has one proper ideal $\{0,2\}$ generated by $2$

Comment: Ironically, $\Bbb Z_6$ is such a ring. In general, if $R$ is a PID, then every quotient of $R$ is a PIR.

Comment: in general, all rings $\mathbb Z_n$ where $n$  is not prime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if $R$ is a PID, then every quotient of $R$ is a PIR.

Ironically, $\Bbb Z_6$ is such a ring, because it is $\Bbb Z / (6)$.

Comment: Everybody leapt on the 'quotient' idea which is of course excellent, but it's really a shame nobody mentioned the *product* of two PIDs is a PIR that isn't a domain. Of course, the example given here is also the product of two fields, so I think it would make a great addition! Regards